# Every open ball is connected

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space such that for all $x \in X$ and all $r>0$,  $\overline{B(x,r)} = \{y \in X \mid d(x,y)\leqslant r\}$
Show that every open ball of $X$ is connected.

Note- I was trying to move with contradiction, but failed!

Comment: It would be interesting to see your proof attempt. You may be on the right track!

Comment: Which notion of "connected" are you trying to prove it with?

Comment: I agree, especially if it's a homework related question, you should post your attempted efforts as well.

Comment: @Arthur I think you may need something more like $[0,2] \cup [3,5]$ to get a counterexample but yeah it seems like this statement isn't true.

Comment: @user2566092 The closure of the open ball around $2$, of radius $1$ is just $[1,2]$ but the set of points at a distance less than or equal to $1$ from the point $2$ is $[1,2]\cup\{3\}$.

Comment: @DanielRust What about $[0,2) \cup (3,5]$ though?

Comment: @DanielRust ok fair enough. At any rate, it seems like something is wrong in this problem, unless connected is supposed to mean locally connected or something.

Comment: @Arthur that does seem to be a counterexample...

Comment: I don't know what's the difference between local connectedness and this one! It's from preliminary parts I can say!

Comment: My attempt: Let B(x,r) be disconnected! therefore B(x,r)= A U B. where A, B are disjoint, non empty open sets in B(x,r). A is open set hence can be written as union of open balls, then can you find a contradiction?

Comment: @UNM What is your definition of connectedness? And why is $[0,2) \cup (3,5]$ not a counterexample?

Comment: a set A is disconnected if it can be written as union of two non empty separated subsets of A.

Comment: Well, then it seems that something is wrong with the problem.

Comment: Agreed, something is wrong with the problem

Comment: If A is connected subset, is int(A) connected? In general! @Arthur

Comment: The answer to that is no. Consider the solid balls $B((0,0),1)$ and $B((2,0),1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Their union is connected but the interior of their union is disconnected.

Answer (score 19):

The statement is not true. Take for example $X = [0,2) \cup (3,5]$. All properties are satisfied, but the open ball $B(1.5,2) = [0,2) \cup (3,3.5)$ is not connected.